# Processing errorsmessages

Tags: java, processing

I want to create a Javacode in processing with a simple square who can be moved by pressing A,W,S and D so i wrote a code to do so but I keep getting errormessages. I was wondering if i could get help to fix the errors.

```
public void setup() {


  k = new karaktar();


  background (#F5CD0C);
  size( 800, 800 );
  strokeWeight( 20 );
  frameRate( 24 );


}

int lastKey = 0;
int lastKey2 =0; 
void keyPressed() {
  if (lastKey != key) {
    lastKey = key; 
    k.move();

  }
}



boolean start = false;
//draw
void draw() { 
      start = true;

}
```

```
class karaktar {

  float x = 400;
  float y = 500;

  boolean alreadypressed = false;

  float xF = x;
  float yF = y-100;
  float xFF = 0;
  float yFF = 0;



  int h1 = 50;
  int w1 = 50;
  int hF = h1;
  int wF = w1;
  float wFF = 0;
  float hFF = 0;




  }



  void move() {

    if (keyPressed) {
       if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {

        y -= 50;
        yF -=50;
      }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {

        x -= 50;
        xF -= 50;
      }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {

        y += 50;
        yF += 50;
      }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {

        x += 50;
        xF +=50;
      }
    }

}
```

The first code is meant to be the playingfield and the second is for the moving square.

Comment: I keep getting errormessages  Please copy the full text of the messages and post it here so we can see them.

Comment: For the moment i got "k cannot be resolved to a variable" I don't quite know why it errors and when i try to remove it or change it the program still errors with new errorsessages.

Comment: I got learned that you need the variable (in this case "k") so when it says that it can't be resolved i don't know what to do

Comment: seems like upper part of your code is missing, are you sure you didnt forget anything?

Comment: You are right, the i didn't include "public void setup() {" får the first one and " class karaktar { " for the second one. I'll edit it in

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your variable `k` in method `setup()` is not declared.

Use `karaktar k = new karaktar();`, or use

```
karaktar k;

someMethod() {
    k = new karaktar();
}
```

// note:

also, it's a convention to name classes with uppercase first letter. I'd suggest renaming `class karaktar` to `class Karaktar`.

Comment: `karaktar k = new karaktar();` will not work because the OP references the variable `k` later in the `keyPressed()` method with `k.move;`, so `k` needs to be an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you've posted, you're likely referencing something somewhere that doesn't exist:

- `k = new karaktar();` only works if the variable `k` is declared somewhere with a line like `karaktar k;`.
- `background(#F5CD0C);` the method `background` must exist, and it looks like you are trying to pass in a hexadecimal number.  In Java, hex numbers are identified by `0x`, not `#`.  I imagine that line should be `background(0xF5CD0C);`
- `size(800, 800);` The method `size` also has to exist.
- `strokeWeight(20);` ditto, must exist somewhere.
- `frameRate(24);` ditto
- `if (lastKey != key) {` variable `key` must be declared somewhere, presumably an `int` to compare to `lastKey`.
- `k.move();` again, `k` must be declared somewhere.

In your class karaktar, variables `keyPressed` and `key` were not declared, and you had unbalanced curly braces.  Below I have fixed the curly braces, but not the variable declarations (in case you aren't showing the code where they are defined):

```
class karaktar {
  float x = 400;
  float y = 500;

  boolean alreadypressed = false;

  float xF = x;
  float yF = y-100;
  float xFF = 0;
  float yFF = 0;

  int h1 = 50;
  int w1 = 50;
  int hF = h1;
  int wF = w1;
  float wFF = 0;
  float hFF = 0;

  void move() {
    if (keyPressed) {
       if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {

        y -= 50;
        yF -=50;
      }
    }

    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {

        x -= 50;
        xF -= 50;
      }
    }

    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {

        y += 50;
        yF += 50;
      }
    }

    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {

        x += 50;
        xF +=50;
      }
    }
  }
}
```